# Nonlinear PDE with intial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hey so I would like to solve the equation: $u_{y} = u_{x}^{3}$ with $u(x,0) = 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}$. I have the characteristic curves but am unsure where to proceed. Thanks!

Edit: Here are the characteristic curves: $\frac{dx}{dt} =3u_{x}^{2}$, $\frac{dy}{dt} =1$, $\frac{dz}{dt} =3u_{x}^{3} + u_{y}$. $\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{dq}{dt} =0$.

Comment: It is hard for us to help you if you don't show us what you have done.

Comment: @mattos I added my work.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3380641/418542) interesting

Comment: @Harry49 Thank you for the useful link, that is essentially what I did in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_y=u_x^3$$
We will try the method of separation of variables.
$$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)\quad;\quad XY'=(X')^3Y^3$$
$$\frac{Y'}{Y^3}=\frac{(X')^3}{X}=\lambda^3$$ 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{Y'}{Y^3}=\lambda^3\quad;\quad Y=(-2\lambda^3y+c_1)^{-1/2} \\
\frac{X'}{X^{1/3}}=\lambda\quad;\quad X=(\frac23\lambda x+c_2)^{3/2}
\end{cases}$$
$$u=\frac{(-\frac23\lambda x+c_2)^{3/2}}{(2\lambda^3y+c_1)^{1/2}}$$
CONDITION :

$u(x,0)=2x^{3/2}=\frac{(\frac23\lambda x+c_2)^{3/2}}{(c_1)^{1/2}} \quad\implies\quad $
$\begin{cases}
c_2=0\\
\frac{(\frac23\lambda)^{3/2}}{(c_1)^{1/2}} =2\quad;\quad c_1=\frac{2}{27}\lambda^3
\end{cases}$

$u=\frac{(\frac23\lambda x)^{3/2}}{(-2\lambda^3y+\frac{2}{27}\lambda^3)^{1/2}}\quad$ and after simplification :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{2\:x^{3/2}}{\big(1-27y\big)^{1/2}}$$