Solution of PDE $u_y - (u_x)^2 =0$
While working on an optimization problem I found that I could rewrite the constraint as having a convex function $u(x,y)$ such that
$u_y = u_x^2$
I wanted to know if there was a way to get a solution with the initial condition
$u(x,0) = f(x)$
For some given convex function $f$.
I found that the very similar hamilton-jacobi equation $u_y+u_x^2=0$ does in fact have an explicit solution this way for $y>0$ given by
$u(x,y) = \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}} f(x-z)+  (z^2/4y)$
Is there a way to do something similar (or perhaps completely different) with my problem. I cant just make a change of variable of $y$ to $-y$ because I need the solution to be defined for $y>0$.
I was also thinking about using a finite elements method.
Thanks in advance for your help.

If you introduce $w = -y$ your equation becomes the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

Yes, but then the solution that I found would only be defined for $w>0$, so $y<0$. And I need it to be defined for $y>0$.

That doesn't matter.  The solution to H-J exists for all $y$, so you can take whichever half you want.

Your problem is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380641/nonlinear-pde-of-form-u-y-fu-x.

@Paul I see, thanks. I'm not very familiar about how to solve the Hamilton Jacobi equation in general. I guess I wouldn't be able to use the specific Hopf-Lax formula I mentioned since the infimum goes to -infinity for y<0. I would also like to be able to check if the solution is convex. Do you know where could I read for answers to these questions?
